# ListBox runs out of screen

Tags: wpf, listbox, bounds

I use ListBox in my project.

When displayed items count is more than free area can take - it runs out of screen.

I mean - no scroll control element, no scroll at all.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show some code? How is the ListBox defined?

Comment: You have probably put your ListBox inside a control that allows it's height to be expanded indefinately. Wrap it with something that restricts it's height and you'll see the scroll bars.